# Can't open windows in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I just updated to Eclipse Juno from Eclipse Indigo.

When I try to open almost any of the windows with options, like `Preferences` or `Switch workspace`, it does nothing. The only ones I've discovered I can open are the `Eclipse Marketplace...` and `Install new software...`.

Edit: I just discovered I can access to `Preferences` through `Install new software...` then `Available Software Sites`.

Comment: Unzip Eclipse Juno into it's own directory, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I did, and it works. Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Yes.  Never, ever update Eclipse.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263423/easiest-way-to-upgrade-eclipse-3-7-to-4-2-juno/11264210#11264210

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc If you want, put it as an answer to select it. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, the same thing just happened to me. Good work, Eclipse! My Eclipse is already in its own directory though.

Comment: Just wanted to comment this has happened to me twice now.  The first time I uninstalled a plugin (I don't remember which one) and it fixed the problem.  Now I'm doing a reinstall of eclipse since something went wrong with my old one (unrelated) and it has happened again... but uninstalling nearly all plugins has not fixed the issue... I just have to start over with the install and take it slow I guess. Edit: Mousefeed plugin removal fixed it.  I think that was the same one I removed last time if memory serves me right.