# 2 different instances of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Indigo.

I want to upgrade to Juno but as i generally [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264210/423980) it is better to make a clean install.

So if I have two instances in my system there are some issues.

1. Copying the workspace folder from one place to the new will I
   lost my commits done with svn ? Is there a way to retrieve them or something?
2. When I want to start *eclipse* Ι just use ALT+F2 and write down *eclipse* . Now that I'm going to have 2 instances how should I know which of the two should Ι execute. How am I going to run Indigo and how Juno?

PS: I don't add ubuntu as a tag I guess some users can answer the second question.

Comment: I've got four versions of Eclipse installed. I just make sure and point everything into the install folder, but I'm also the only user on this machine.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm the only user too. Just to make it clear do I need a new workspace or I can use the same ?

Comment: I've got Indigo and Equinox in the folder, and in `/configuration/config.ini`, I have `osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace` setup for both. Both work fine. If it makes you itchy, change it to `osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/indigo/workspace`. I've also got Aptana 3, which is Eclipse, and it's setting is `osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace`.