# How to properly upgrade Eclipse Indigo to Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am attempting to upgrade my Eclipse Indigo to the latest version, Juno. I have already downloaded it. However, I have noticed my Android SDK is not installed. Is there a way to simply "recover" my previous plugins and Android SDK from the Indigo version? Also, it would not allow me to open my previous workspace. How is there a simple way to import my projects? Or do I have to import them as a new project every time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either upgrade your existing installation in place (without any re-installation) by adding the Juno update site (like you would for any other plugin) or you can import all plugins from your old installation easily into your fresh installation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264964/44089.

Answer (score 0):

Your better off using eclipse to reinstall the droid sdk again in your new eclipse; nevertheless, If you added the SDK as a dropin, its a simple matter of opening up the dropin directory and copying that to your new version of eclipse's dropin directory.

If it's anything like my android build it's in your plugin directory.  I wouldn't suggest copying your plugin libs over to your new eclipse (ex: `cp -Rv ./eclipse/plugins/*droid* ./newEclipse/plugins > ~/copiedFiles.txt` ), as I'm not 100% certain this way addresses startup issues or further xml configuration necessary for eclipse to behave properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "dropin"? I believe when I installed the Android SDK, I used the URL to the Android Developer page in the "Install New Software" tab in Eclipse (I could be wrong. It was a long time ago and I've rarely used Android but need to now). I know I have the Android SDK saved in my documents in a separate folder.

Comment: There's a dropin directory that is part of your eclipse install that you can use to add new features to eclipse. It doesn't sound like that is what you did previously.  You can take a look at eclipse versus plugins for more info about the differences @  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins

Comment: Okay, I think I'll just end up reinstalling the Android SDK via the Android developer's page. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the Android ADT plugin for Eclipse by clicking help > Install new software > add then entering the URL available on the Android developer's page for the Eclipse ADT plugin. Then after successfully installing the plugin and restarting Eclipse, it gave me the option to select where my SDK is located. So I didn't have to re-download all the APIs.