# Eclipse Upgrade

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ide

I am using Eclipse 3.7 as default from Ubuntu software center.

I want to upgrade Eclipse to kepler version so I added a 
[repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/)

I am getting following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20130828-0031 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130828-0031)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)I want to upgrde eclipse to kepler version so i added a respiratory
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.2.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.2.0.dist)
    Equinox Provisioning Core 2.3.0.v20130327-2119 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.3.0.v20130327-2119)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.1.0.dist-829DFnfFKlR6A96 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.dist-829DFnfFKlR6A96)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core [2.2.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.2.1.v20130827-1605 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.2.1.v20130827-1605)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core [2.3.0.v20130327-2119]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function Source 1.2.1.v20130827-1605 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.1.v20130827-1605)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.2.1.v20130827-1605]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 RCP Management Facilities Source 1.2.0.v20130828-0031 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature.source.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130828-0031)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.source.feature.group [1.2.1.v20130827-1605]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBYLdOsDvEEi8m9FbLOK8 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBYLdOsDvEEi8m9FbLOK8)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.1.0.dist-829DFnfFKlR6A96]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBYLdOsDvEEi8m9FbLOK8]
```

Please Help me on this

Comment: Don't upgrade.  Create a new Kepler Eclipse and new workspaces to go with Kepler Eclipse.  Carefully (one at a time with full testing) move projects to the new workspaces.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that should be an answer

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Thanks.  You can upvote this answer if you wish.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263423/easiest-way-to-upgrade-eclipse-3-7-to-4-2-juno/11264210#11264210  The more things change, the more they remain the same.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  Thanks. Ii would do that

Answer (score 0):

Don't upgrade. Create a new Kepler Eclipse and new workspaces to go with Kepler Eclipse. Carefully (one at a time with full testing) move projects to the new workspaces