# Eclipse IDE upgrade from Kepler to Luna went very bad

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

I upgraded my Eclipse IDE for Java developers from Kepler to Luna using the **worst** possible upgrade feature of Eclipse and it messed up my current workspace totally.
I added the update site for Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4
and selected all and installed.
Then it took an hour to figure out the conflicts and finally when it installed, my Eclipse is behaving very erratic.

1. I can see welcome screen changed and couple of new menu items.
2. Eclipse market place is gone, I don't know how to get it back.
3. Intermittent freezes forcing me to restart.
4. My Grails setup is gone and I can't install from Market was gone.

Can anybody suggest what is the right procedure to upgrade? (I read the wiki and it doesn't work) and I am looking for methods that actually worked for you.

*These are the times I some times cringe in pain and crave for a managed or paid IDE, as a simple task like "upgrade" should be so damn easy and click of a button"*

Comment: I generally just do a new install for the major releases.

Comment: I agree with @greg-449, do a clean install and export/import settings from old to new.

Comment: I would uninstall the version you installed, download a fresh copy, install a fresh eclipse and import the projects you want.

Comment: My main problem is I have many plugins installed. Is there a way to get all the plugins also? thx.

Comment: My fears came true, I exported preferences, but it didn't export my SVN repositories. I have 9 of them! And I don't know what it copied and what it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse is notoriously known for being hard to upgrade to a new version in place.

Download and unzip a new, fresh Eclipse and import the extra things you have installed from the old installation.

Then import your existing projects again.  Maven projects should be explicitly imported as such.

Comment: I didn't find a way to export all the plugins. Is there any?

Comment: You do not need to export plugins.  Eclipse can import directly from an existing Eclipse installation.

Comment: If you have a lot of plugins, in your old Eclipse do: File > Export... > Install > Installed Software Items to File.
Then in the new Eclipse: File > Import... > Install > Install Software Items from File. You can also import plugins directly from the installation as   Thorbjørn mentioned, but it sounds like it be flaky according to the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264964/382885

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can be upgraded in place, provided you add both the "release" and the "updates" repository. Your mistake was adding just the "updates" one.

In your case, you should have added the following two repositories:

- Luna release repo: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
- Luna updates repo: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4