# Method reference shortcut transformation in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, java-8, keyboard-shortcuts, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In Spring Tool Suite

```
(Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290649
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2))
```

Is there a shortcut to go from something like:

```
Function<String, Integer> func = str -> Integer.valueOf(str);
```

to something like this:

```
Function<String, Integer> func =  Integer::valueOf;
```

(and backwards) via a keyboard shortcut?

I am aware of Ctrl+1 key combo, but it doesn't seem to offer the method reference conversion, hence this inquiry:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need Eclipse 4.5 or greater, because that's when [this particular assist](https://bugs.eclipse.org/439601) was first published.

Next you should avoid the "unused" warning on the variable, because otherwise content assist will jump to the nearest warning / error rather than proposing a change unrelated to any problem in the current code (this is not strictly necessary, but makes the next step easier).

Finally, you need to position the cursor on the `->`, because that's the only piece of syntax definitely identifying the lambda.

[image: convert to method reference assist]

See also the first item in the [4.5 "New-&-Noteworthy", Section on JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/jdt.php).

Comment: Thanks, I'll attempt 4.5 - what would be the cleanest/more appropriate way to upgrade the STS - can I simply upgrade all the suggested plugins or will I be better off installing a brand new version of STS and changing my shortcuts?

Comment: For upgrading STS please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29490233/4611488 (while you are at it: 4.6 has been released this year, so you may actually want to skip 4.5).

Comment: I didn't forget, simply didn't get to try re-installation yet, please stay tuned.

Comment: I have Neon 3 (4.6.3) - i followed the advice here, but the option still does not show up.

Comment: @Stephan Herrmann: Thank you.  Seems to be working on STS ver. 4.0.0.M7.  As for verifying the procedure to upgrade STS, I ended up just installing the brand new version from scratch so I will not attest to the steps there.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Select the lambda expression `"str -> Integer.valueOf(str)"` and press `Ctrl-1`. The first entry in the quick-fix list should be something like "convert to method reference".

Comment: Ctrl-1 doesn't seem to work, see the screen shot above.

Comment: perhaps it is [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430656), though it is said it is fixed with luna 4.2.2 that you are using. also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453083/eclipse-luna-r-no-content-assist-for-java-8-method-references

Comment: Stephan is, of course, right. You need at least an Eclipse 4.5-based development environment to use this content-assist. Sorry that I forgot to mention that.