# What is the reason for this error when getting an update with Eclipse 3.7.2?

Tags: eclipse

I get this error when I am trying to install an update with that an online class has instructed me to get. I am using Eclipse 3.7.2.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile229917962076303828.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile229917962076303828.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5003512112024214543.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5003512112024214543.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2971733495012787064.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2971733495012787064.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4955573181956746191.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4955573181956746191.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9085126581421997760.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9085126581421997760.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7931321307443251455.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7931321307443251455.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile409771845537393959.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile409771845537393959.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile513281332038811320.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile513281332038811320.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1649782267569845321.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1649782267569845321.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4614832727283252956.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4614832727283252956.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6573889540074706707.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6573889540074706707.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2168577465462220063.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2168577465462220063.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1026107981981112100.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1026107981981112100.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8608122838916083965.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8608122838916083965.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5332631103751026474.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5332631103751026474.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5360759831561917997.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5360759831561917997.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6632907844118631199.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6632907844118631199.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1165322697850813382.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1165322697850813382.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8917795193671536705.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8917795193671536705.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,4.3.0.201508182223.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8915887263535671107.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8915887263535671107.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264210/300257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to install pydev. The [requirements](http://www.pydev.org/download.html) for pydev are a minimum of Eclipse 3.8 or 4.3 (so the current Eclipse Mars (4.5) is probably best).