# Should I Uninstall Eclipse, or Just Install a New Version on Top?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-neon

To preface, I am a student and have limited experience with IDEs. My situation is that I currently have two versions of Eclipse on my machine (OSX El Capitan), one being a C/C++ IDE (Mars) and the other is a Java IDE (Mars.2).  I am interested in upgrading to Eclipse Neon for my Java IDE.

Would it be a good idea to uninstall my current Mars.2 version, or just install Neon on top of what I have?

Or, is there a another simple way to upgrade?

If the solution involves uninstalling my Mars.2 version, what files/directories do I need to delete so that my C++ IDE remains functional?

I apologize for the newbie question, but I wanted to get an expert's take that I can bring into my (hopeful) career.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to uninstall existed Eclipse since it's allowed to let multi eclipse run on the same machine.

If no big change has been made from original eclipse, I suggest just download a new version eclipse and unzip it to a different folder from existed eclipse folder based on instructions from [FAQ How do I upgrade Eclipse IDE?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F)

> We strongly recommend against unzipping over your existing Eclipse
>   version as unexpected side effects may occur, including (but not
>   limited to): nausea, vomitting, shortness of breath, corrupt
>   installation.

You can then point the new Eclipse version to your existing workspace(s) and it will load with all your projects and preferences intact.

If your you have added many plugins and preferences to current Eclipse, please follow [Easiest way to upgrade eclipse 3.7 to 4.2 (Juno)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263423/easiest-way-to-upgrade-eclipse-3-7-to-4-2-juno) to migrate the plugins and preferences. Although that's a bit of a dicey process, since many plugins would be incompatible or need to be updated themselves. Better to just install whatever third-party plugins you use into the new Eclipse installation.

Comment: It's also recommended to create a new workspace, or at least create a backup of your workspace if you decide to upgrade it a newer Eclipse version.